# onChange for multiple input type radio

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have the following:

```
<input type="radio" name="zec" onchange="calc1();calc2();calc3()" value="0" checked>0
<input type="radio" name="zec" onchange="calc1();calc2();calc3()" value="1">1
<input type="radio" name="zec" onchange="calc1();calc2();calc3()" value="2">2
etc...
```

Is there a way to write the onchange event once for the radio type name="zec"? If there are more elegant solutions, I am all eyes.

Comment: Well, you could narrow that with `onchange="calc()"` and `function calc() { calc1(); calc2(); calc3();}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
var elem= document.getElementsByName('checkThing');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elem, function(e){

     e.addEventListener("change", function() { 
         calc1();
         calc2();
         calc3(); 
     });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use jQuery, like so:

```
$('input[name=zec]').change(function () {
    calc1();
    calc2();
    calc3();
});
```

You would put this in a `<script></script>` tag right before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: No **jQuery** I guess.